# How to use Clang kit with Qt Creator on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, clang, qt-creator

(this question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533043/how-to-use-clang-as-a-compiler-with-qt-creator-on-windows) but is not the same)

I'm using QtCreator on Windows platform, usually with vc toolchain.
sometimes with MinGW-W64, so for now, I'd like to try clang for some reasons.
unlike the post above - I don't use Qt library , just qtcreator as IDE, so I suppose I don't need to re-build it and QtCreator for a using clang kit, is it correct?

there are a few questions about that:

1. CLang distribution doesn't contain platform or even c/c++ runtime library, should i use it from vc kit? or/and MinGW runtime? how to switch between?
2. Correct my understanding please if it's wrong - for Win platform, clang has two options to use: 1) normal use - clang.exe ,as on any other platform 2) clang-cl.exe - additional layer which "looks like" cl.exe, and just parses cl command line keys and calls normal clang.
3. as I understand there is no LLDB for Windows platform , can I use GDB or CDB depends of the used runtime lib and binary format of the executable?

and finally - how to configure all this in qtcreator?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps apply only to MSYS2 64-bit installation of QT Creator 4.5.1 (install instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38337759/1505939)), where you also have MinGW-w64 and mingw32-make installed on MSYS2; and you are building a non-QT C or C++ application.

These instructions use QMake, because QBS doesn't support MSYS2 clang. Well, QMake doesn't support it either, but I did figure out how to add support to QMake and I didn't figure out QBS.

There is QMake support for MSVC-clang but it outputs MSVC makefiles, so you can't build it with MSYS2 make. So that does not apply to us.

1. Install clang with `pacman`. I used `pacman -Ss mingw-w64-x86_64-clang`, your flavour may vary.
2. Add support for clang to QMake:

   1. In the MSYS2 shell, go into `/msys64/mingw64/share/qt5/mkspecs/`
   2. Do `cp -a win32-g++ win32-clang-msys`
   3. Edit `win32-clang-msys/qmake.conf` and change `gcc` to `clang`, and `g++` to `clang++` (2 places each)
   4. In the same file, take out `-fno-keep-inline-dllexport -mthreads` which are not supported by clang.
3. In QT Creator, set up a new Kit:

   1. Go to Manage Kits.
   2. Add a Custom Compiler for C and browse to the installed path (`/mingw64/bin/clang.exe` under your MSYS2 install).
   3. Add a Custom Compiler for C++ as `clang++.exe` in the same place)
   4. Add a manual Kit called `Clang` and set those two compilers as its compilers.
   5. In the manual kit config set "Qt mkspec" as `win32-clang-msys`
   6. Set "QT Version" to something. Even though I am using a non-QT project, the IDE doesn't like using the kit if "Qt version" is set to None.

Now you can attempt to build your project with the `Clang` kit and QMake.

I initially tried with QBS and the build failed due to [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QBS-1322) . But the build commands do succeed if I copy-paste them and cut out the bogus `-target` switch.  So for QBS users I guess you have to switch to QMake in the meantime until they fix that bug.

---

**Troubleshooting:**  I sometimes got an error `Project ERROR: failed to parse default search paths from compiler output`. This is a problem with QMake's lack of support for clang.  The error tended to not occur if I built in a subdirectory of the `.pro` file, but did occur if I built in a sibling directory.

As a workaround: go back into `win32-clang-msys/qmake.conf`. Change the first `clang` back to `g++`. Then "Run Qmake" (from QT creator or commandline), then change it back. The first time you run QMake it writes the file `.qmake.stash` and then does not need to generate it again.  The contents of this file were bogus for me but building seemed to work anyway.

**Undefined references:** I found that linking with `-static` produced a bunch of undefined references to `__imp__cxa_` names. Not sure what the problem is here but maybe related to the bug with generating `.qmake.stash`. I guess the Qt developers would need to officially add non-MSVC Clang support to QMake.

**Multiple definitions:** The CLang linker gave multiple definitions for inline DLLexport functions. I found no workaround yet for this; g++ has `-fno-keep-inline-dllexport` to avoid this problem but CLang 5 does not support that flag.

Comment: Also more info about adding compilers: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html